# CSS: display table-cell on links with border-radius: incorrectly displayed border and unwanted margins

Tags: css, border, css-tables

My goal is to make a variable number pagination links with border radius so it looks all nice.
It should also, under small screen, take the whole width of the screen and links must be evenly spaced and without margin.

But then,

```
.pagination{
display:table;
    font-size:0.1px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.pagination a{
    background-color:#8bf;
    display:table-cell;
    font-size:1rem;
    border:1px solid #48f;
    min-width:3rem;
    height:2rem;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.pagination a:first-child{
    border-top-left-radius:1rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius:1rem;
}
.pagination a:last-child{
    border-top-right-radius:1rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius:1rem;
}
@media(max-width:470px){
    .pagination{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Will square the borders while still rounding the background.

Furthermore, there is a margin between links that can't be taken out. [Edit: That was taken out]

I cannot have a specified width for the links their number vary between 1 and 4.

http://jsfiddle.net/md6s998p/

Comment: A Jsfiddle.net demo would be useful but it's not entirely clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks I never used this before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...although it's not clear to me precisely what the question is you are asking, I **think** it's related to the border.

You can still use the `border-radius` property for rounding and substitute a `box-shadow` for the border.

I've exaggerated it in this example

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/md6s998p/1/)

```
.pagination a{
    background-color:#8bf;
    display:table-cell;
    font-size:1rem; 
    //border:1px solid #48f; /* remove this*/
    min-width:3rem;
    height:2rem;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px 0 red; /* add this...or variant */
}
```

Frankly, I think you would find it easier to structure this as a `ul/li/a` list rather than just as a series of links in a **paragraph**.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D for the box-shadow idea :)